# Type XX is not assignable to type YY

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript, i need to export a function,
but it raises the following error

> Type 'string | IconProps' is not assignable to type 'string |
> undefined'.   Type 'IconProps' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.(2322)

I have simplified the code, the IconProps contains more properties than the example.

```
interface IconProps {
    icon?: string; // Right icon
  }
type Props = {
  icon?: IconProps | string; // Right icon
};

export function Icon({ icon = 'material-symbols:10k'}: Props) {
  return (
      icon={icon}
  );
}
```

Comment: Include what you are returning in the `Icon`. The problem is that the component that you are returning accepts `string | undefined`, not `string | IconProps`

Comment: This is really confusing, you have an optional parameter that could be a `string` or a object including `{ icon: string }` , i think it would be better to just create two different variables